# Custom Controller Action Url Rewrite from config.xml Not working

Tags: magento-1.9, configuration, xml, url-rewrite

I need to the rewrite custom controller action url, I have tried the below code in `config.xml`with the help of [this](http://www.endreywalder.com/blog/magento-url-rewrite-using-config-xml-and-regular-expressions/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4768681/url-rewriting-for-magento-module). When I entered the url as http://www.website.com/orders instead of http://www.website.com/test_order/index/order , it shows 404 error.

```
<frontend>
    </routers>
        <test_order>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Test_Order</module>
                <frontName>test_order</frontName>
            </args>
        </test_order>
    </routers>
</frontend>
<global>    
    <rewrite>
        <test_order_index_order>
            <from><![CDATA[#^/[orders]/([-\A-Za-z0-9.]+)?/?([-\A-Za-z0-9.]+)?/?([-\A-Za-z0-9.]+)?$#]]></from>
            <to><![CDATA[/test_order/index/order/]]></to>
            <complete>1</complete>
        </test_order_index_order>
    </rewrite>
<global>
```

Comment: You can create custom url redirect in URL rewrite management from admin.

Comment: Yes,Thanks. But there is possibilities to do rewrite in xml.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below code works fine,

In `config.xml`

```
<global>    
    <rewrite>
        <test_order_index_order>  <!-- Unique Id -->
            <from><![CDATA[#^/orders[\/]?$#]]></from>  <!-- Url To be entered in browser-->
            <to><![CDATA[/test_order/index/order/$1]]></to>  <!-- Router to map -->
            <complete>1</complete>  <!-- To load the current module xml file -->
        </test_order_index_order>
    </rewrite>
<global>
```